# send string query alongside user name and password ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to send **`command=login&`** string along side username and password collected from the form, like

**`login.php?command=login&name=something&password=main`**

```
<form id="login" action="https//login.php" method="GET">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="password">password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>


$('#login').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    data: "command=login&" + ('#login').serialize(),
        $.get('https://login.php', data, function() {
            //  $('#').html(data);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
  $.get('https://login.php?command=login&' + $('#login').serialize(), function() {
  //  $('#').html(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input field to your form. You should also be sending the form via `POST` and not `GET` since you are sending sensitive information.

```
<form id="login" action="https://login.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="login">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  >
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="password">password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" >
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Then remove the string portion from your `data` attribute like this:

```
$('#login').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = $('#login').serialize()
  $.post('https://login.php', data, function(results) {
  //  $('#').html(results);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but there is a slight problem, the '@' symbol isn't showing its showing "%40" instead.

Comment: `serialize()` will do that. You can `urldecode()` with php

Comment: how can I display the response in a <div> tag in the same page?